# Get Folders content using Graph SDK - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, microsoft-graph-api

Actually I'm using Microsoft Graph SDK for get my SharePoint content and upload files.

```
var driveItems = await _graph.Sites["myCompany.sharepoint.com"]
                             .Drive
                             .Root
                             .Children
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();
```

But using this code snippet, I'm stuck on root folder. Which means I can't get the files located on a folder, or upload a file in his subfolder, for example.

How can I navigate between folders using this Microsoft Graph SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get the list of files and folders by using the code which you shared and I have tested it as below.

**Used the Code :-**

```
var driveItems = await graphClient.Sites["soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45"]
                             .Drive
                             .Root
                             .Children
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();

                foreach(var items in driveItems)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(items.Name);
                }
```

**Result:-**
A folder and a file.

[image: The]

The only reason that you are not getting those files could be due to the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions) that you don't have in your scope. Please add Sites.Read.All permission and try to read the results.

Comment: I have permission for list drive content. How do you navigate between folders? Some kind of ID after site address?

Comment: Yes, to check for sub folders or files in a folder you need to use the folderid and then items/{folderid}/children as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#list-children-of-a-driveitem-with-a-known-id).

Comment: The code looks like this `var driveItems = await graphClient.Sites["soaadteam.sharepoint.com,c1178396-d845-46fa-bc0c-453d2951dad5,19ee9a1e-001d-48f1-9ee8-b0adfde54e45"]
                             .Drive
                             .Items["01LPJ34YTH6LJ5T3KULJBLHMGFEWEZXW5E"]
                             .Children
                             .Request()
                             .GetAsync();`